# How to select option dropdown data show in two line with HTML tag?

Tags: html

I want to create HTML drop down data in two lines with different HTML tags.

Here's my attempt:

```
<select class="form-control" data-placeholder="Product..." multiple>
    <option value="">Product...</option>
    <option value=""><b>Danish Patel</b><label>PhD Developer</label></option>
</select>
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Pretty certain it's not possible with the standard html multiselect. You might be able to bold part with a custom multiselect like bootstrap or jquery ui. I would suggest making your title clearer by updating it to "bold part of text in a multiselect".

Comment: Yes, I want formate Like : Danish Patel<br/>Php Developer

Comment: Please also provide any another demo for above issue.

Comment: Hang on a second, I think I may have found a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Thank God for workarounds! It is possible; just use <s>`:before`</s> `::before` and <s>`:after`</s> `::after` along with `data-` attributes.

This way you can have the bold, multi-line before or after the main content of the `option`.

```css
option.bold-before::before {
  content: attr(data-bold);
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
}
option.bold-after::after {
  content: attr(data-bold);
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" data-placeholder="Product..." multiple>
    <option value="">Product...</option>
    <option value="" class="bold-before" data-bold="Danish Patel"><label>PHP Developer</label></option>
    <option value="" class="bold-after" data-bold="CSS Wizard"><label>Yaakov Ainspan</label></option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want to use two colons for those pseudo-elements `::before`, not one  which is a pseudo-class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: You can ignore the standard or follow the standard. It's never good to ignore the standard but, yes, browsers will currently accept one semicolon. Until they change it and all your properties mess you up.

Comment: Fine, if you insist.

Comment: Oh, it's not me insisting. It's every browser vendor on the planet who are involved in writing the standards.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion and reply to Ques.

Comment: This dropdown work fine with CSS but my dropdown is  multiple selection so response show in ul li so this css not effect in my dropdown...

Comment: What do you mean?